# HtmlUnit: Get UnexpectedPage after downloading a file

Tags: java, download, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit

I need to download different files in different pages with htmlUnit webDriver. I cycle on the pages and for every page I click on a input field to trigger the download.
For the first download, I click on a HtmlInputElement (a submit button) which gives me back the file. After that, the HtmlPage becomes an UnexpectedPage. Examining the WebResponse in the UnexcpetedPage I still find the file already downloaded. 
How to workaround?

code:
    [...]

```
public void test(HtmlPage htmlPage){
    List<?> checkBox = htmlPage.getByXPath("//tbody[@id='TestID:ricerca_report:tb']/tr[child::td[contains(text(),'TEST')]]/td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']");

    for (int j = 0; j < checkBox.size(); j++) {
        HtmlCheckBoxInput checked = (HtmlCheckBoxInput) checkBox.get(j);
        checked.setChecked(true);
    }

    writeResponseHtml(htmlPage, spOp);
    InputStream input = null;
    try{
        HtmlSubmitInput htmlSubmitInput = htmlPage.getElementByName(param.getNameAttribute());
        WebResponse webResponse = htmlSubmitInput.click().getWebResponse();
        extractOriginalFileName(webResponse, spiderInfo.getFileName());
        if( checkAndSaveFileExtension(webResponse) != null ){
            input = webResponse.getContentAsStream();
            downloadFile( input );
            spiderInfo.setFileName("work/output/spider_logs/");
        }else
            spiderInfo.setSpiderState(SpiderStates.DOWNLOAD_ERROR);
    }catch ( Exception e ){
        logger.error("getOperation download exception; " + spOp + "; Exception: " + e);
        spiderInfo.setSpiderState(SpiderStates.DOWNLOAD_ERROR);
        page = null;
    }
    writeResponseHtml(htmlPage, spOp);
    HtmlTableDataCell tableCell = htmlPage.getFirstByXPath(param.getContainsElement2());
    Page p = tableCell.click(); // Here i got the exception
}

[....]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone encoutered the same problem; I solved using **PageCreator**:

```
PageCreator dpc = new DefaultPageCreator();
HtmlPage detailPage = null;
for (int j = 2 ; j<= 11; j++){ // there are 10 pages
detailPage = (HtmlPage)dpc.createPage(htmlPage.getWebResponse(),webClient.openWindow(htmlPage.getUrl(),"ew Window"));
detailPage = ((HtmlElement)detailPage.getFirstByXPath("MYXPATH")).click();
detailPage = ((HtmlElement)((HtmlPage)detailPage ).getFirstByXPath("MYXPATH2")).click(); // download element
webClient.setCurrentWindow(htmlPage.getEnclosingWindow()); //go back to main window
}// end FOR
```

where htmlPage is the main page.